# No wifi with Atheros Qualcomm AR|5005G(s) 802.11bg on Lubuntu 17.10

Tags: wireless, atheros

My wifi card is Atheros Qualcomm AR|5005G(s) 802.11bg, AR2413/2414

It is neither hard-blocked nor soft-blocked. Power managment is off.
The **Wi-Fi Networks** button in the menu is disabled.

There is an additional info about my config from wireless.info script:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 05 Jan 2018 12:48 EET +0200

Booted last: 05 Jan 2018 00:00 EET +0200

Script from: 05 Dec 2017 03:13 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.14.0-041400-generic #201711122031 SMP Sun Nov 12 20:40:36 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Lubuntu

##### lspci #############################

09:02.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [1179:ff31]
    Kernel driver in use: 8139too

09:04.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR2413/AR2414 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5005G(S) 802.11bg] [168c:001a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. AR2413/AR2414 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5005G(S) 802.11bg] [144f:7094]
    Kernel driver in use: ath5k

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2717:ff40  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

PRODID_1=""
PRODID_2=""
PRODID_3=""
PRODID_4=""
MANFID=0000,0000
FUNCID=255

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

ath5k                 135168  0
ath                    24576  1 ath5k
mac80211              675840  1 ath5k
cfg80211              524288  3 mac80211,ath,ath5k
wmi                    20480  1 toshiba_acpi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp9s2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp9s2' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: wlp9s4: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp9s4' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp9s2    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp9s4    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       434     1  0 12:40 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp9s4
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        AR2413/AR2414 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5005G(S) 802.11bg]
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ath5k
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.14.0-041400-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp9s4' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.4/0000:09:04.0/net/wlp9s4
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2,1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   d47b67af-bc1e-4dea-b144-aab7bf326629 | MykolaU-plus
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   ea5126b3-9180-48df-b699-e47b2cc55f36 | MykolaU

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp9s2
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         8139too
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 0.9.28
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp9s2' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.4/0000:09:02.0/net/enp9s2
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MykolaU-plus]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MykolaU-plus | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp9s4' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=MykolaU-plus
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=ignore

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MykolaU]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MykolaU | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlp9s4' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=MykolaU
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Kiev (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp9s2    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp9s4    12 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp9s2    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp9s4    No scan results

##### module infos ######################

[ath5k]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.14.0-041400-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath5k/ath5k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for 5xxx series of Atheros 802.11 wireless LAN cards.
author:         Nick Kossifidis
author:         Jiri Slaby
srcversion:     01FB964A002B27138405B3F
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
name:           ath5k
vermagic:       4.14.0-041400-generic SMP mod_unload 686 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)
parm:           fastchanswitch:Enable fast channel switching for AR2413/AR5413 radios. (bool)
parm:           no_hw_rfkill_switch:Ignore the GPIO RFKill switch state (bool)

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.14.0-041400-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     555BBBB9D4FCA58A05E7C0D
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
name:           ath
vermagic:       4.14.0-041400-generic SMP mod_unload 686 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.14.0-041400-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     E427240664ACBE186C6AE39
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       4.14.0-041400-generic SMP mod_unload 686 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.14.0-041400-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     784748F60B5390682360B5B
depends:        
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.14.0-041400-generic SMP mod_unload 686 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath5k]
fastchanswitch: N
nohwcrypt: Y
no_hw_rfkill_switch: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/ath5k.conf]
options ath5k nohwcrypt=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/custom-wireless.conf]
options ath5k nohwcrypt

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/libpisock9.conf]
blacklist visor

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   22.047309] ath5k 0000:09:04.0: registered as 'phy0'
[   22.718619] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x64
[   22.718621] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   22.718626] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   22.718627] ath: Regpair used: 0x64
[   23.273690] ath5k: phy0: Atheros AR2413 chip found (MAC: 0x78, PHY: 0x45)
[   29.996790] ath5k 0000:09:04.0 wlp9s4: renamed from wlan0
[   35.776207] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp9s2: link is not ready
[   35.776403] 8139too 0000:09:02.0 enp9s2: link down
[   35.776761] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp9s2: link is not ready
[   35.810796] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp9s4: link is not ready (repeated 4 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I found out that my wifi network was using a 'bgn' type while the wifi card was supporting a 'bg' only. So, firstly, I change that in the wifi settings of the usb wifi router.
2. I changed the encryption type to AES only
3. Figured out my network was broadcasting on the 13th channal, while the card was supported less channels (11 or 12, don't remember). I switch network to the 11th channel.

After that my network appeared at connections menu. Thanks. I will appriciate any additional comments under this post with hints or corrections as for written above, since I am pretty nubie either in networking or unix. Maybe not of all points wouldn't to be done or changed. Thanks a lot for advance.

At least, this case works for me.